# Chrome Extensions Optional Permissions wont evaluate callback function

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I've encountered a problem using the [Optional Permissions API](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/permissions.html) for Chrome Extensions.  In the following minimal example of an extension, I expect the script to first check whether a permission exists, and if not, request permissions and modify a token to say the permission exists. I implemented this via the options page for an extension, and success is indicated by a square turning from red to blue. Failure is indicated by the square remaining red.

Here's the funny thing, the script only works if I set a breakpoint in Chrome's Inspector and proceed step by step through it.  It fails to work (wont even prompt for permissions) when the extension is run without breakpoints. I submitted this as a [bug for Chrome](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=122449), but I really wonder if I'm doing something wrong.

manifest.json

```
{
"description": "Permissions Tester",
"name": "Permissions Tester",
"options_page": "options.html",

"optional_permissions": [ "http://api.labs.crossref.org/" ],

"version": "1.0.0"
}
```

options.html

```
<script>
function setCrossrefPermission() {
    var perm;

    chrome.permissions.contains({
        origins: ['http://api.labs.crossref.org/']
    }, function(result) {
        if(!result) {
            chrome.permissions.request({
                origins: ['http://api.labs.crossref.org/']
            }, function(granted) {
                perm = granted;
            });
        } else {
            perm = true;
        }
    });

    return perm;
}

function hitIt() {
    if( setCrossrefPermission() ) document.getElementById("notify").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
}
</script>

<html>
<body>

<div style="width: 100px; height:100px; background-color:red;" id="notify"></div>
<input type="submit" id="button" onclick="hitIt(); return false;" value="Accept Permission" />

</body>
</html>
```

I uploaded this as a CRX [here](http://web.missouri.edu/~mdmnq5/comp/perm_test.crx) for ease of installing and trying.  Or you can simply load the unpacked extension above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't call `chrome.permissions.request` in the `chrome.permissions.contains` callback function because it isn't in the correct context. Also, you don't actually need to check for the permission beforehand either.

```
function setCrossrefPermission() {
    chrome.permissions.request({
      origins: ['http://api.labs.crossref.org/']
    }, function(granted) {
      return granted;
    });
}
```

For an already accepted permission prompt the warning message isn't displayed.

Comment: I came up with the example based on trouble I was having with permission requests being handled asynchronously (javascript lines continue to execute while prompt for permission is up).  Looks like I'll need to be more clever about forcing synchronous scripting... maybe: while(perm==undefined).